# Is there a source that writes that R' Maimon kept the Chovos Halevavos on his table?

Tags: chovos-halvavos

I heard that the Rambam's father, Rabbeinu Maimon, used to keep the Sefer Chovos Halevavos on his table. (Which was told to me to illustrate his high regard for the sefer.) I have seen accounts of the Rishonim arranging it to be translated (e.g. the Raavad), (which would show their regard for this sefer), but I haven't come across a source for this.

Thank you for any help on the matter

Comment: I have heard this too, unlikely that a historical record of this exists.  See https://books.google.ca/books?id=RO2_nOOfdcsC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=maimonides+father+the+duties+of+the+heart&source=bl&ots=j8oLRej33k&sig=SeqLXj4uxCSOBLbfqnTz8YIqUZ8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG09Gl1L3cAhWC7IMKHZYaCMoQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=maimonides%20father%20the%20duties%20of%20the%20heart&f=false, which claims that Rabbeinu Maimon and Rabbeinu Bachya ibn Paquda were friends...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות The dates don't really work out for them to have been friends.